# Update all bindings in IIS to replace an expiring SSL Certificate with a new one

Tags: powershell, iis

I wish to iterate through all IIS bindings and find any that use a particular certificate (the one that is expiring) and replace them all with a new certificate. Without changing anything else about the binding.

Powershell seems the obvious solution to this.

Answer (score 9):

I found a great script to find any IIS bindings that have a particular 'old thumbprint', and replace the cert with the new cert specified by it's thumbprint.
The original script I found [here](https://www.bauer-power.net/2021/09/simple-powershell-script-to-update-ssl.html#.YmiAKtpByUk) ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220426222751/https://www.bauer-power.net/2021/09/simple-powershell-script-to-update-ssl.html#.Ymhx8drP2Uk))

This works given the new cert is already installed.

Removing a bit of cruft the script boils down to this:

```
$OldThumbprint = "########################################"
$NewThumbprint = "########################################"

Get-WebBinding | Where-Object { $_.certificateHash -eq $OldThumbprint} | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Replacing Cert For "  $_ 
    $_.RemoveSslCertificate()
    $_.AddSslCertificate($NewThumbprint, 'My')
}
```

Comment: I had real trouble finding this answer so I thought I'd share it here with a bit more keyword juice.

Comment: There's a RebindSslCertificate() to make it even shorter

Comment: Would be cool if we could assign certificates automatically by filtering candidates in store by matching domain with CN/SAN for outdated certificates (`Where-Object { $_.certificate.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)}`). (Full disclosure: we have dozens of certs / domains)